# asynchronous tweet button, image flickers

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter, asynchronous

I am using the tweet button, with this asynchronous Javascript loading code below. When I place it at the bottom of my HTML the background image of the tweet button flickers, because it is loaded last.

I noticed in firebug it is pulling this via an `iframe` and the image is a background specified in CSS. Is there anyway to load the image locally to override the background image in the `iframe`?

```
var b = document.createElement('script');
b.type = 'text/javascript';
b.src = ('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
var a=document.getElementById("deferedjs");
a.parentNode.insertBefore(b,a);
```

Answer (score 0):

iframe is in another domain so you can not touch it.

If the problem is with the image not being loaded, you can load the image on your page with an image preloader so it will be cached.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = img.onerror = function(){ alert('hello'); }
img.src = "http://example.com/imgs/someImage.png";
```

Comment: I ended up loading a background image first via css on top of the image in the exact spot where the javascript loads the image. I then hid the text and it does not flicker now.